# Не могу зайти в настройки биоса или загрузить линукс

Tags: linux, железо, grub, bios, uefi

После установки arch linux с помощью anarchy пропала возможность входа в настройки биоса (`F2`). Грузился только арч. Команда `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` не работает. Пытался сбросить настройки биоса, вытаскиванием батарейки биоса. Сделал только хуже - теперь даже граб не грузится. Подробнее:
- Запускаю ноутбук
- Появляется логотип биоса и снизу полоска в которой написано `[F2] for setup`
- Нажимаю `F2`
- Надпись сменяется на `Please wait...`
В идеале после этого должно открыться меню настройки биоса.
До этого у меня с этой надписью запускался граб (через секунд 5), чего не должно быть.
Теперь просто чёрный экран пару секунд и перезагрузка.

Как я понимаю, установщик включил fast boot, который не даёт зайти в настройки биоса.

Модель ноутбука: np530u3b-a04ru

Вопрос: как можно вернуть систему в работоспособность? По сути нужно зайти в настройки биоса, а дальше уже я сам смогу разобраться. Что можно/нужно сделать, не прошивая биос? Или прошивка биоса единственное решение?
Материнка: lotus 13

Comment: попробуйте найти на материнке перемычку clear cmos

Comment: Перемычку такую в явном виде не вижу. На другой мат. плате мини ПК есть такая. А на ноуте такой нету.

Comment: Вынимайте батарейку, с отключенным аккумулятором несколько раз в течении минуты замыкаете и размыкаете + и - слота батарейки отвёрткой или пинцетом.

Comment: Не помогло. Всё также

Comment: Я эту проблему решил на ноутбуке Acer так:  поставил пустой диск, залил на него винду. Из под винды перепрошил BIOS на более новую версию. Выключил,включил ноутбук. и заработало.

Comment: Винды под рукой не имею. Попробую с неё загрузится. Но мне кажется, что я поломал что-то и она не загрузится

Comment: Может быть попробовать отключить жесткий сбросить питание по батарейки и без хдд включить и войти в биос

Comment: Я пробовал. Как выше написал, пишет `Please wait`. И потом перезагружаться.

Comment: Теперь похоже только перепрошивка через программатор.